# Are phrases and words terms?

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes we have a concept which can be described with multiple words only. As far as I know, we use the word *phrase* to describe these multiple words. Can I use the word *term* if I want to talk about both single- and multi-word definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

> - [term](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/term) - "a word or group of words having a particular meaning, especially in a specific field"

- "recirculation" and "slow leak" are engineering terms.
- "apoptosis",  "mitral regurgitation" and "congestive heart failure" are medical terms.
- "litigation" and "Habeas Corpus" are legal terms.
- "metalanguage" and "leading question" are linguistic terms.